# move_uploaded_file fails but error number (1) seems wrong

Tags: php, html, session, file-upload

I am using PHP version 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus).  I am using the following code to upload a file.

```
<form action="https://myWebSite.com/uploadLibraryFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file" style="font-size:5mm; font-family:times-new-roman">Select library file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" accept=".cdf,.CDF"  /></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit[]" value="submit" />
        <input type="hidden" id="LoggedIn" name="LoggedIn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="UserName" name="UserName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] ?>">
</form>
```

uploadLibraryFile.php has the following form.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();        // This MUST be used to allow session variables to perist on next page.
?>
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>

<?php

$target_dir = "../librarydropbox/";

//    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn']=$_POST["LoggedIn"];
    $_SESSION['UserName']=$_POST["UserName"];

    // Ensure user is logged in
    if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Session login not set")
            </script>
            <?php
            header("Location: otherPage.php");
    }

    // Process file
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
            echo "_FILES: " . print_r($_FILES["file"]) . "<br>";
            echo "_FILES[tmp_name]: " . print_r($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) . "<br>";
            echo "_FILES[name][0]: " . print_r($_FILES["file"]["name"][0]) . "<br>";
            echo "_FILES[name][0]: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][0] . "<br>";
            $src =  $_FILES["file"]["name"][0];
            echo "Src: " . $src . "<br>";
            echo "Dst: " . $target_file . "<br>";
            echo 'upload_max_filesize = ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . "<br>";
        if (move_uploaded_file( $src, $target_file))
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"][0]). " has been uploaded.";
        else
            echo "Not uploaded because of error #" . print_r($_FILES["file"]["error"]);
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

The output I get is as follows.

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => temp.cdf ) [type] => Array ( [0] => application/octet-stream ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpaBSrgR ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 14 ) ) _FILES: 1
Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpaBSrgR ) _FILES[tmp_name]: 1
temp.cdf_FILES[name][0]: 1
_FILES[name][0]: temp.cdf
Src: temp.cdf
Dst: ../librarydropbox/temp.cdf
upload_max_filesize = 200M
Array ( [0] => 0 ) Not uploaded because of error #1
```

My understanding is that error 1 means that uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.  However, I checked php.ini and upload_max_filesize is 200M.  The size of temp.cdf is 1KB and is an ASCII file consisting of the following text.

```
minimal text
```

Comment: You're outputting before header here.

Comment: I added a header, and edited my question accordingly, but it made no difference.  Thanks,

Comment: Can you check upload_max_filesize with ini_get, maybe its value is changed from 200M somewhere?

Comment: Hi @Joni.  I tried that (and updated the question accordingly).  upload_max_filesize is still 200M.  Thanks,

Comment: That isn't what I meant. By "outputting before header" means that there should not be any HTML before the session gets started. Enable error reporting and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I modified my code to be as shown above.  The output remains the same.  I also did not get any new errors in  /var/log/syslog or in  /var/log/apache2/error.log.  Thanks,

Comment: Had to figure it out myself but some waste of space voted it down.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I should have used

```
$src =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0];
```

instead of

```
$src =  $_FILES["file"]["name"][0];
```